# Sentence making error

Tags: grammaticality

I couldn't make myself understand in English when I visited America for the first time.

There is an error in the sentence. Can you please sort it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the first line the sentence that contains the error? Right now it just sounds like you're telling us you had a hard time with English in America.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's spammy.

Comment: @Bread: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you are trying to ask. It might be

> I couldn't make myself understood in English when I visited America
>   for the first time.

which means that nobody understood what you were saying. Or perhaps

> I couldn't make myself understand English when I visited America for
>   the first time.

Which means that you didn't understand what other people were saying.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean one of two things by this sentence. As it stands the sentence is unclear and non-standard/ungrammatical.

You visited America, but you could not make yourself *understood* (passive tense) OR
You visited America, but you could not induce yourself to (come to) understand the English spoken by other people (reflexive use).
You might legitimately believe both were the case, but perhaps the first is more likely. In English, one understands something, active transitive verb with object. Alternate, one is understood, passive, meaning, to be understood (by others). A person who does not understand themselves is typically having a philosophical or existential problem, beyond the scope of grammar and usage.
I hope this explains it.